# Testing method without parameters

Tags: java, file, unit-testing, junit

This is one my first times posting on here so I'll do my best to be concise and clear.

My method below takes in 0 arguments and reads through a certain file looking for a tag to echo to the console:

```
protected static serverVersion() {
    String output = "";
    try {
        File lsbRelease = new File("/path/randomFile.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(lsbRelease));
        boolean isMatch = false;
        String line = "";

        // run through file and find the tag
        (...)
```

The three different possibilities of the method are:

1. Read the correct file, find the tag and echo the tag
2. Read the correct file, does not find the tag and outputs a message to the user
3. Not able to read the file, throw exception

**Is there a way for me to write tests that simulate these three different situations?** I thought about using the Rule for TemporaryFolder/Files, but I don't know how I would make the test use the temporary file I make.

I know I could pass in a string as a parameter for the file path and then use a TemporaryFile to test, but I want to avoid changing the original method. Also, I want to avoid using another framework (i.e. Mockito).

Comment: Dependency injection is your friend. Pass a "fake" file in as a parameter and check that it succeeds and fails under the right conditions.

Comment: Doesn't this require me to change the original method?

Comment: In its current form the method is too tightly coupled to implementation details which make it difficult to unit test in isolation. If the goal is to simulate then some refactoring is going to be needed. Hence the suggestion for Dependency INVERSION

Comment: Unfortunately yes, you'll need to change it. Although this isn't a bad thing. Having changeable code is good. You want to make it testable which is a step in the right direction.

Comment: Appreciate the comments @BrandonIbbotson. I will most likely do this, but anyone else - feel free to give other suggestions!

Comment: @WilliamHamiltonGrosset *"but anyone else - feel free to give other suggestions!"* I can only think of one other suggestion: using PowerMock(-ito), but IMHO that's either a surrender to bad design or a confession to refuse writing clean code.